# Visual Studio 2017 - how to run the application using external tool ApiTrace

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017. I would like to run my application using an external tool - ApiTrace. The syntax looks like this:

```
apitrace trace --api [gl|egl|d3d7|d3d8|d3d9|dxgi] /path/to/application [args...]
```

How to run my application using ApiTrace from Visual Studio ?

Comment: Pretty unclear what benefit you expect from running this tool from VS.  Right-click the project > Properties > Debugging and change the Command and Command Arguments settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in `ApiTrace` instructions, **Visual Studio 2019 or later** is required.

See here for requirement and instructions : https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.markdown#microsoft-visual-studio

Comment: Please add more details on the solution from the link you proposed in your answer